# C++ error when running code

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++ and i cant figure a problem out.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int userContinue = true;
int userContinueString;
int getUserInput() {
    int userInput1;
    int userInput2;
    cout << "Please enter your first number: ";
    cin >> userInput1;
    cout << endl << "Please enter your second number: ";
    cin >> userInput2;
    cout << endl << "The result of the two numbers together: " << userInput1+userInput2;
    userInput1 = 0;
    userInput2 = 0;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    while (userContinue == true) {
        getUserInput();
        cout << endl << "Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ";
        cin >> userContinueString;
        if (userContinueString ='Y') {

        }
        else {
        userContinue = false;
        }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

The code works fine until i input "Y" ant then it keeps looping as shown here: [Video](https://i.gyazo.com/2b50b058c1624c6f271e8c02bc09a11b.mp4)

Comment: `int userContinueString;`??? why are you using an `int` for a "string"?

Comment: lol ty. As i said i am very unfamilliar with the language. What should i use instead?

Comment: Not sure how a C++ application could be generating a _Python_ error...

Comment: Also, use two equals signs for comparison `if (userContinueString == 'Y') {`

Comment: I tried this but now the program shuts down whren entering Y?

Comment: Does the compiler not give you any warnings? It should know you didn't mean what you actually typed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you compile your code with some warning switches such as `-Wall -Wpedantic`. These switches will help you. For instance, in your original code, my compiler prints the following warnings:

```sh
prog.cpp:25:28: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    if (userContinueString = 'Y') {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
prog.cpp:25:28: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
    if (userContinueString = 'Y') {
                           ^
        (                       )
prog.cpp:25:28: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    if (userContinueString = 'Y') {
                           ^
                           ==
1 warning generated.
```

Then, I fix the corresponding line with `==`, which was already suggested in the comments. Then, your comparison should be case-insensitive. Finally, you would like to compare `char`acter objects with respect to `'y'` or `'Y'`:

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int userContinue = true;
char /* not int */ userContinueString;
int getUserInput() {
  int userInput1;
  int userInput2;
  cout << "Please enter your first number: ";
  cin >> userInput1;
  cout << endl << "Please enter your second number: ";
  cin >> userInput2;
  cout << endl
       << "The result of the two numbers together: " << userInput1 + userInput2;
  userInput1 = 0;
  userInput2 = 0;
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  while (userContinue == true) {
    getUserInput();
    cout << endl << "Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ";
    cin >> userContinueString;
    if (std::tolower(userContinueString) == 'y') {

    } else {
      userContinue = false;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT.** I have improved the answer by taking into account David's comment below. Note the use of `#include <cctype>` and `std::tolower`.

**EDIT.** I have tried improving the answer further by trying to address the "learning C++" comment below:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <class value_t,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<value_t>::value,
                                  int>::type = 0>
struct Calculator {
  Calculator() = default;

  explicit operator bool() {
    while (true) {
      std::cout << "Valid operations: +, -, *, /, 0 (exit)\n";
      std::cout << "What would you like to do: ";
      if (!getUserInput(operation)) {
        std::cerr << "Wrong input for operation\n";
        continue;
      }

      switch (operation) {
      case '0':
        return false;
      case '+':
      case '-':
      case '*':
      case '/':
        break;
      default:
        std::cerr << "Wrong input for operation\n";
        continue;
      }

      std::cout << "Please enter v1: ";
      if (!getUserInput(v1)) {
        std::cerr << "Wrong input for v1\n";
        continue;
      }

      std::cout << "Please enter v2: ";
      if (!getUserInput(v2)) {
        std::cerr << "Wrong input for v2\n";
        continue;
      }

      calculate();
      return true;
    }
  }
  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Calculator &c) {
    os << "v1 " << c.operation << " v2 = " << c.result;
    return os;
  }

private:
  char operation;
  value_t v1, v2, result;
  std::string line;

  void calculate() {
    switch (operation) {
    case '+':
      return calculate(std::plus<value_t>{});
    case '-':
      return calculate(std::minus<value_t>{});
    case '*':
      return calculate(std::multiplies<value_t>{});
    case '/':
      return calculate(std::divides<value_t>{});
    case '0':
      return;
    }
  }
  template <class Func> void calculate(Func &&f) { result = f(v1, v2); }

  template <class T> bool getUserInput(T &t) {
    std::cin >> line;
    std::istringstream ss{line};
    return (ss >> t) && (ss >> std::ws).eof();
  }
};

int main() {
  Calculator<double> c;
  while (c)
    std::cout << c << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or simply convert `tolower()` or `toupper()` for the comparison and you only need to compare a single case.

Comment: Slightly beside the point, but these are C utilities, and for learning C++ you (@M3Me5) would benefit more from C++ string manipulation and other utilities (you're already using `cout`/`endl` as opposed to `printf` and other C functions.)

Comment: @JohnP, thanks for the heads-up. By the way, am I supposed to integrate other changes for the source, too, such as `int`->`bool` preference for the logical variable, getting the global variable inside `main`, etc?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt, but I think if the question was about an error then you've answered perfectly well. As a rule I do things like taking `std::ostream&` as a parameter and returning it again instead of hard-coding `std::cout` into each function for the same reason, but it's a question of "learning C++" as opposed to "learning to program in C++". In this case I would lean toward `for(bool userContinue = true; ...)` or `if(userContinueString != 'Y') break;` and in fact I would not name it a string if it isn't `std::string` (or `const char*`) but "learning C++" implies learning syntax.

Comment: Regarding the globals in particular, none of them really need to be there, and variables like `userInput`1/2 are reset as if they were globals when they're local to the function scope. I would recommend something like `do { getUserInput(); } while(getUserContinue());` to the author, but again, this isn't about polishing the program. I think the `int` type as opposed to `bool` could be a valid choice if other values were planned (leading to a `switch`, maybe controlling add/subtract/etc. in addition to quitting.)

Comment: OK @JohnP, fair enough. I have added to my answer some excerpt that, hopefully in a nice way, demonstrates some nice `C++` features such as encapsulation, operator overloading, templates, `string` parsing, and `type_traits`.